# 3D view transform like Morning Routine App

Tags: android, view, 3d

someone can tell me how to
create this transformation of view ?
I tried opengl , but I was not helping and I did not understand crabs!

[image: Morning Routine ScreenShot]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It´s done using a BitmapMesh  canvas.drawBitmapMesh(..); which basically is a grid of coordinates. Check out BitmapMesh.java in the Api demos for a simple example.

The coordinates are then mapped up to a set of Paths using PathMeasure to achieve the wavy effect. I hope to get the time to write a blogpost and opensource the curtainmenu in the future.

Comment: any blogpost on this yet? :)

Comment: @Tobbbe check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28825611/sliding-drawer-curtain-animation) link.

Answer (score 0):

[Curtain effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v3UMi.gif)
[AwesomeDrawer](https://github.com/Android1404/AwesomeDrawer)

```html
<com.hx.curtain.drawer.CurtainContentLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/curtain_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:behind_menu="@layout/menu_left"
    app:content="@layout/layout_curtain_content"
    app:h_waveCount="5"
    app:maxRate="0.5"
    app:v_waveCount="1.1" />
```