# Sliding Drawer Curtain Animation

Tags: android, animation

I recently came across an application [Morning Routine](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.havchr.mr2&hl=en) which is loaded with great animations. The one I got stuck with is the curtain animation used on the Sliding Drawer.

How it looks:

[image: animation]

Does anyone know how to achieve that animation? Using [FoldingLayout Library](https://github.com/Cheesebaron/FoldingLayout) is not smooth enough to achieve it and is entirely different thing.

Comment: Not sure if you can see the deleted answer in the related Q&A, but it links to the following github repo: https://github.com/7heaven/bitmapMesh. Based on a brief look, the visual effect (and underlying tech) appears very similar.

Comment: @MH., Thanks a lot! This is the same thing I've been looking for. Post it as an answer, if you may.

Comment: How can we get the drag down animation used in this application ?(used in the main alarm screen, i.e. dragging down changing the toolbar images)

Answer (score 0):

Honestly its really simple read comments below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <cheesebaron.folding.FoldingLayout
        android:id="@+id/fold_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
         <!-- put you curtain layouts here, listview e.t.c -->
    </cheesebaron.folding.FoldingLayout>

    <!-- put any other layouts here -->

</LinearLayout>
```

Why don't you try and see what happens.